# ipCore.min.js impresspages trying to load theme resource in Ip/Internal/Core/

Tags: resources, themes, impresspages

Working with bootstrap 3  when including glyphicons I am getting a 404 error Ip/Internal/Core/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

http://pasteboard.co/XQwHBbe.png

the Icons are displayed properly but I cant avoid ipCore.min.js in Admin state from trying to load it within ip/internal/Core

the theme structure is as follows:

Theme/ThemeName/assets/fonts/

this is the full console log http://pasteboard.co/XRNb9zz.png

Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

`ipCore.min.js` is a JavaScript file. It doesn't relate with the error. Those fonts are actually loaded by `admin.css`. ImpressPages admin elements are based on Bootstrap 3. So don't mix admin with your own theme.

What you found is actually a bug which is now added to the issue list - https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/issues/491 (you can vote for the solution).